# Encoding Turing machines in binary in a simple way that gurarentee unique readability

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, encoding-scheme

I may come across  something like (let $X$ be a binary representation of a Turing machine $M$), I know that we can easily encode the description of the machine as sequence of numbers (by assigning a number to every symbol and arranging the description in some particular way) and then encoding this sequence by a single number (using prime numbers and powers as in Godel numbering) and then considering the binary representation of this number as the encoding of the machine, but such an encoding would be difficult to manipulate and use in say a simulation.

If we want to encode Turing machines in binary form so that we can use this encoding in a simulation, such encoding should be *simple* so that we can recover the instructions of machine easily for example, A pair $(q_7,x)$ would be represented as the binary number of 7 followed by some (binary) distinguished mark that indicates the end of the number that represents that state and then a representation of the symbol $x$ but I can not see how can we come with such a "mark" that do the job and guarantee unique readability.

So, suppose that we want to encode every pair $(p,q)$ of natural numbers in binary. Suppose that we will do that by exhibiting the binary representation of both p and q with a (binary) mark in-between, is there any trick that we can use to add this distinguished (binary) string that will tell us where the first number ended and where the second starts? *If not, then How can we encode Turing machines in binary so that, we guarantee well-readability and we can "recover" the instructions of implementation easily.*

Comment: Encode $0$ as $00$, $1$ as $01$, and 'break' as $10$. Optionally, encode 'end' as $11$. Of course, there are more space-efficient schemes, but this should be one of the simplest. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I think you are confusing "useful in proofs" and "useful in practice". Gödel numbers are *not* intended for use in actual machines; of course we'd use some readable language.

Comment: @Raphael, Ok but I don't see how a turing machine can simulate  another turing machine if its representation was done using Godel numbering, of course I know it can be done (we can recover it easily by factoring the numbers in an appropriate way) but I can not see how can the Turing machine (not me) recover the instructions in this case. Of course we can argue that as there are an algorithm that recover the instructions from the encoding so by Church-Turing thesis we guarantee the existence of some Turing machine that do this, but I can not see how to program such a machine.

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen, Yes I think that this is good enough, thank you very much :)

Comment: @MathsLover I don't understand your question. You know that there is an algorithm (Yes, Gödel numbers are reversibly computable), but you don't know how a TM would do it? Well, it'd just  implement that algorithm. The details depend on the specific encoding and how you want to approach the simulation itself.

Comment: @Raphael,You are completely right.  Maybe because I'm not familiar with binary arithemetic (How can I factor a binary number etc ... Although I can in principle do that calculation,  it's psychologically uncomfortable  since I did not get used to it ) this is why I find it somehow uncomfortable. I'm familiar with Godel encoding from mathematical logic where we use decimal representation. Doing the same in binary is somehow (psychologically) uncomfortable for me since I didn't get used to them much except in few occasions (I come from mathematics background not CS, we don't use binary much)

Comment: @MathsLover Well, you are not *forced* to use binary. Use whatever finite alphabet you want.

Comment: @Raphael, Yup sure , except if the author asks you to do it in binary or if his arguments assumes that alphabet is  binary. Also, it's useful to get use to other conventions which I want to do to overcome this psychological problem.

Comment: That's a common trick. Do everything concrete with any alphabet with the knowledge that you can just encode it in binary (cf ASCII), and do all proofs in binary because it keeps your proofs neater. All you need to fill the gap is binary encoding for stuff, which is trivial.

Comment: this  is a nice trick, I can see why this is done.